# Bind mousewheel with jquery 1.8+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using `Jquery 1.8.3` on my site.

I can't bind mousewheel with this jquery version , but `1.4.2` version is bind mousewheel successfully.

Please give me a solution to solve this problem ?

*Note* : I need to bind mousewheel with only `1.8+` version. Because other plugins are depends on `Jquery 1.8+`

My example code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mouse Wheel</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
body { text-align: center; }
#res
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 128px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 0;
    $(document).bind('mousewheel',function(e){
        if (e.wheelDelta > 0)
        {
            $("#res").text(++num);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#res").text(--num);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="res">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example with your code, just add the mousewheel javascript plugin : http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Mouse Wheel</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://flexicontent.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1517/trunk/com_flexicontent_v2.x/site/librairies/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
body { text-align: center; }
#res
{
    margin-top: 200px;
    font-size: 128px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var num = 0;
    $(document).bind('mousewheel',function(e, delta){
        if (delta > 0)
        {
            $("#res").text(++num);
        }
        else
        {
            $("#res").text(--num);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="res">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Gilles Hemmerlé! I want to bind mousewheel with `Jquery 1.8+ version`

Comment: Then replace the version of jquery by the one you want ? http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js. Replaced and still work fine on my example.

Comment: Effectively, there was a bug with firefox. Take the new mousewheel file that I put on the example and everything should rox ^^